# Unity Get Pixel Coordinate Values from RectTransform

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, rect

I am in need of a way to obtain the pixel coordinates of a rect transform.

x position where 0 is the left of the screen and y position where 0 is the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`.

Convert the object origin.

Convert the object origin+width.

Convert the object origin+height.

Your pixel coords are Array[origin.x, origin.y, origin.x+width, origin.y+height]

Answer (score 0):

In 3d there are not pixels. Only a units in unity 3d.

```
float x = transform.x;
float y = transform.y;
```

You will get units in x, y.

If you working with textures you might use Texture2D, it has some methods for pixel working.